# JAX-WS WebService Client\Server architecture - request has null parameters

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, jax-ws, wildfly

i'm having a problem with a jax-ws client\server architecture, i've got server deployed on my machine for test with WildFly 8 (and also in a remote machine with websphere application server)

The problem is that the webservice request received by the server contains only null variables. This is a request generated with soap UI:

```
<dataObject>
           <sen:codeAg>321</sen:codeAg>
           <sen:numberProt>TT2838199932</sen:numberProt>
</dataObject>
```

in this example both dataObject.codeAg and dataObject.numberProt debugged on the server, are null.
But if i manually edit the request like this, removing "sen:":

```
<dataObject>
       <codeAg>321</codeAg>
       <numberProt>TT2838199932</numberProt>  </dataObject>
```

On the server i can see that both variables are valorized (dataObject.codeAg=321 and dataObject.numberProt=TT2838199932).

This has also been tested client side with Java wsimport and a simple main Class to connect to my server, in this case on the server both variables are null like the first example with the "sen:".

What could be the problem? I'm using JAX-WS RI 2.8 for publishing and compiling my server.

EDIT: The package-info.java generated client side:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://test.com/senfoo", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

package com.test.senfoo;

Comment: You probably need to send a XSD-valid payload in your request document.  The JAXB unmarshalling will typically unmarshal unrecognized elements to 'null' (rather than say blowing up with an exception).    The reason your request is invalid would seem to be an issue with the `elementFormDefault=qualified|unqualified` setting. There are a couple reasons why this could happen.

Comment: I've tried several combinations, still no luck... The strangest thing is that this was working like three months ago with the same jax-ws libs and configurations. There must be something else, the only thing that changed is the version of websphere and the version of wildfly.

Comment: OK, what's your WSDL/XSD?   Maybe past some of the key JAXB annotations (like the ones on package-info.java).

Comment: `sen:` is XML namespace. Does the request have sen: defined in it?

Comment: Where i can see if it's defined in the request or not? By default for example soapui generates the requests with "sen:" so ... i think that's defined in it

Comment: If you look at the full "working" request, is it valid according to the schema?   If so then maybe you're using SOAP UI in some incorrect manner to generate an incorrect payload.   If the working request is not valid, then you (obviously) have some other problem.